# Can you initialize a function? - Javascript

Tags: javascript, initialization, instance

I have this function here, I need to work with this other function called `OrderRepository` in another file.

**main.js**

```
function main() {

var orderRepo = new OrderRepository();

// Your code here

}
```

**orderrepository.js**

```
function OrderRepository() {

}

OrderRepository.prototype.getYesterdaysOrders = function 
  getYesterdaysOrders() {
  var yesterdaysOrders = [{ array of objects }],

 return yesterdaysOrders;
};
```

These were given as examples to use, 1 question rolled into 2 parts:

1) `var orderRepo = new OrderRepository();`

Can you initialize a function like this?

2) In the **orderrepository.js**:

```
function OrderRepository() {

}
```

is being called in **main.js**, but nothings inside of it, this was given as-is in the assignment, is this just a typo and really they meant to throw everything inside that function or am I missing something?

Shouldn't it look like this?

**Expected**

```
function OrderRepository() {

OrderRepository.prototype.getYesterdaysOrders = function 

  getYesterdaysOrders() {

  var yesterdaysOrders = [{ array of objects }],

  return yesterdaysOrders;

 };
}
```

Comment: Tips for asking questions: make your code as relevant as possible and as short as possible while displaying your problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Diving deeper into JavaScript, the language is hard to understand. JavaScript is not really OOP (imho), at least it does not implement the common OOP concept. Some call it object-based language. There are no classes. Recent ECMA Script standards do implement the `class` keyword, however, it is syntax sugar. Used with the `new` keyword it builds the same objects as you can achieve by 'constructor' functions.

Everything in JavaScript is an object, even numbers and functions. Every function can act as constructor function. The `new` keyword call a constructor function with a newly creates empty object as the function's `this` context. The function can do what it wants. If it does not return anything, its `this` context is returned by the `new` expression.

Since there are no classes, there is no inheritance. Some inheritance-like behavior is achieved by the prototype concept. In most cases the constructor will return nothing and sometimes modify the `this` object by adding properties. Methods are properties  holding a function object. The object in the `new` context of a constructor call will have a prototype object reference as the `__proto__` property. This is copied by the `new` operator from the `prototype` property of the called constructor function. The default is an empty object.

```
// empty constructor function
function OrderRepository() {

}

// define a function property on the constructor's prototype object
OrderRepository.prototype.getYesterdaysOrders = function 
  getYesterdaysOrders() {
  var yesterdaysOrders = [ /* array of objects */ ],

 return yesterdaysOrders;
};

// create an empty object with a `__proto__` property holding a
// reference to the object { getYesterdaysOrders: function(){/*code*/} }
var obj = new OrderRepository();
```

Now, when the method invocation `obj.getYesterdaysOrders()` is tried, JavaScript will look if there is such a property defined in `obj`. If not, it looks if there is a reference in `obj.__proto__` and the property name is searched the properties of `obj.__proto__`. If not, the same step is repeated until it was found or the `__proto__` property in the chain is `null`. Since `obj.__proto__.getYesterdaysOrders` is defined, it is checked if it is a callable function object and finally invoked with a `this` context of `obj` since we called `obj.getYesterdaysOrders()`. Otherwise an error is thrown.

NOTE: Even if the major browsers do expose the `__proto__` property, it is not part of the standards. Do not use it directly (except for debugging at development time) and even more important: do not manipulate it. If you really need to get or manipulate a prototype (`__proto__`) of an object instance after construction, use the methods of the builtin `Object` object.

Upon your last edit: Your expected code would define a new function object in `prototype` on each instantiation (and thus constructor invocation). This is not what you want, it's just needless overhead.

Comment: So, that empty constructor function is there by design and not an error, along with the rest of the code?

Comment: @mph85 Exactly. It creates an empty object with no individual properties. However, all the instances created by `new` share the function object, i.e. the method. Methods can even dynamcally create properties later as long as the object is not sealed. (see `Object` methods in documentation)

Comment: @mph85 In other words: All instances share the same prototype - predefined in `prototype` of the constructor function and copied to `__proto__` of the instance. The method is defined in the shared prototype. Also notice that a prototype is always an instance, not a constructor. So a common pattern to replace a base prototype is: `ConstructorFunc.prototype = new ProtoConstructorFunc();`

Comment: @mph85 Open the DevTool's console in your browser and type `OrderReository`. It should show you a function object (after running the code in your question on top level). You can inspect it by clicking on it. Type `OrderReository.myProp = 123;` Try `OrderReository` again and you will find your new property - and `prototype` as well.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the first part, it looks like this assignment is dealing with how to create instances of objects in JavaScript as that is what the `new` operator does.

You can find more information regarding [`new` on the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new).

Regarding the second question, it is dealing with how to create objects that inherit methods. So, yes it is empty, until you get to the `prototype` expression.

The **expected** code would not give you the inheritance in this case. Notice how `OrderRepository` is repeated inside the function, which would be invalid. Javascript requires you to add inheritance to the special `prototype` property. Code that is added to the `function` declaration, would be scoped to the `function` only in that case.

You can find more information about [`prototype` on the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain#Inheriting_methods).

Comment: thanks, ive read that, so a function is essentially an object so you should be able to initialize it, but what about my 2nd question, am i seeing something wrong?

Comment: so, shouldn't the 2nd part be inside that `OrderRepository` function?

Comment: Updated answer for clarification. It can be a bit confusing as inheritence is certainly an advanced topic for JavaScript.